# Store Series of 0s and 1s in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, string, node.js, store, bit

I'm using MySql and Nodejs. I need to store a huge string made of only 0s and 1s. (This is a map grid. 0 = Can Move, 1 = Can't move.)

Ex: 00000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000
...

Should I take that string, encode it into a base64 string and store it that way? Then when I need it, I decode it? If so, how would I do it, using Nodejs/Javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're storing appears to compress easily, why don't you use the built-in MySql [COMPRESS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) function

Raw:

```
mysql> select length('00000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000');                                                                                                                                                                                             
332
```

With COMPRESS

```
mysql> select length(compress('00000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000'));                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
23
```

Comment: Working. Thanks. My 9216 long string became only 629 long once compressed. :D

Answer (score 0):

Don't store a string, store binary.

Here's an example of a way you could convert that data to binary.  Hopefully you can reengineer things so that your map data is never represented as a string in the first place.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string data =
            "00000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000";

        var arrayLength = data.Length/8;
        if (data.Length%8 != 0)
            arrayLength++;
        var binaryData = new byte[arrayLength];

        byte nextByte=0;
        var k = -1;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            var j = i%8;
            if (j == 0)
            {
                binaryData[++k] = nextByte;
                nextByte = 0;
            }

            var bit = int.Parse(data[i].ToString());
            if(bit==1)
                nextByte |= (byte)(bit << j);
        }
        binaryData[k] = nextByte;
    }
```

Comment: Problem is that the maximum length of BINARY is the same than VARCHAR which is too small for my maps.

Comment: No way.  You can store 8 times as much.  a "1" is taking 8 bytes when it only needs to take 1 bit. 64 of your characters takes 512 bytes, but can be represented in 8 bytes.  for example 1010001111000000101000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 could be represented by the number 0xA3C0A00000000000

Comment: If you weren't storing that data as a string you would therefore never have to convert it.